# In RISC-V, when will an interrupt be handled?

Tags: linux-kernel, operating-system, interrupt, riscv, xv6

I learned that every core in RISC-V can handle an interrupt. So when one core is running in u-mode, will it trap into s-mode and handle the interrupt? Or only in s-mode core can handle this interrupt?

I tried debug xv6 os, seems like every uart interrupt is trapped from s-mode (result show on backtrace is `kernelvec`)

To be short, the question is: when will an interrupt be handled, assume core is in x-mode and interrupt is a y-mode interrupt?